# "Access is denied" error in IE6

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, window-object

This code is giving me error on line 10 in IE6. That is, `var ref = ...;`

What is the error here?

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>JavaScript Popup Example 3</title>
</head>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript1.2">
function MyClass()
{
    this.OpenWindow = function()
    {
        var ref = window.open ("http://www.google.com", "mywindow", "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=100,height=100");
        ref.moveTo(0,0);
    }

}
</SCRIPT>
<body onload="javascript: new MyClass().OpenWindow()">
<H1>JavaScript Popup Example 3</H1>
</body>
</html>
```

The message:

```
A run-time error has occurred. 
Do you wish to debug? 

Line:10
Error: Access is denied
```

Comment: javascript line numbers in IE can be misleading. what is the actual error, and what are the visible symptoms? what happens when the code is executed? the first thing i notice is that `onload` doesn't need the `javascript:` prefix, as it is a javascript event handler, but it shouldn't cause an error, either

Comment: No. Removing javascript: is not working. The error is being shown up again.

Comment: It would be really stupid if this is the cause, but what are the chances its that space between "window.open" and the bracket?

Comment: @JMSA: indeed, it shouldn't resolve the issue. i'd still like to know what the actual error message that is showing up is.

Comment: Message:"A run-time error has occurred. Do you wish to debug? Line:10 Error: Access is denied"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you open a window with a page from a different domain, you don't get a reference to the window back. The ref variable is null.

If you want to move the window, you have to open it without a page, move it, then load the page in it:

```
var r = window.open ('', 'mywindow', 'location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=100,height=100');
r.moveTo(0,0);
r.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here - ref.moveTo(0,0); - on most security settings this action is unavailable

also, javascript: on onload just creates a label "javascript"

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>JavaScript Popup Example 3</title>
</head>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
function MyClass()
{
    this.OpenWindow = function()
    {
        var ref = window.open("http://www.google.com", "mywindow", "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=100,height=100");
        ref.moveTo(0,0);
    }

}
</SCRIPT>
<body onload="new MyClass().OpenWindow()">
<H1>JavaScript Popup Example 3</H1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: javascript security settings... in ie6? o_O

Comment: No. The same error is occurring. You can test it on your own IE.